# Is there a natural way to build a volume form on an oriented Poisson manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, orientation, poisson-geometry

**Editet question**

Let $(M, \pi)$ be an oriented Poisson manifold. Is there a natural way to build a volume form from the Poisson bivector $\pi$?

**Original question**

*It is always possible to build a volume form on a symplectic manifold; for example if $(M, \omega)$ is a $2n$-dimensional symplectic manifold, then $\Omega = \underbrace{\omega \wedge \dots \wedge \omega}_{n\text{ times}}$ is a volume form.
Is there an analogue way to orient Poisson manifolds?*

Comment: $\lbrace f,g\rbrace=0$ for all $f,g$ is always a Poisson bracket. Define it on a non-orientable manifold

Comment: Thanks @Giulio, you're right, my question did not make much sense for an arbitrary Poisson manifold. I edited it to address the case of an oriented Poisson manifold.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $(\mathcal M,\pi)$ be an orientable Poisson manifold.

A *natural* volume form could be probably intended as: every Hamiltonian vector field preserves this volume form.

In this acception, *Poisson-Lichnerowitz (PL) cohomology* (often called just *Poisson cohomology*) provides a criterion. I am not an expert in the subject, so I am essentially digesting what I read on
[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_manifold#Modular_class%20.).

Let us recall the definition of the *first* PL cohomology group, denoted $H^1(\mathcal M,\pi)$. It is the quotient of the group of Poisson vector fields (by definition, those $X$ that preserve the Poisson structure, i.e., ${\rm Lie_X}\pi =0$) over the subgroup of Hamiltonian vector fields (by definition, those $X=X_H$ for some $H\in\mathscr C^{\infty}(M)$, where $X_H(f)= \lbrace f,H\rbrace$ for all $f\in\mathscr C^{\infty}(M)$). (Recall that every Hamiltonian vector field is a Poisson vector field.)

Fix a volume form $\lambda$ and recall that any volume form on a manifold allows for the definition of *divergence* (a scalar denoted ${\rm div}_\lambda\,X$) of a vector field $X$, namely by requiring the identity
$$
{\rm Lie_X}\lambda = ({\rm div}_\lambda\,X) \lambda.
$$
(A nice exercise is to check that this reproduces the standard notion when the manifold is an open set in $\mathbb R^n$ and $\lambda=dx^1\wedge\dots\wedge dx^n$.)

Define, for a fixed $\lambda$ volume form, the *Poisson modular vector field* $M_\lambda$ by its action as a derivation on functions:
$$
M_\lambda:f\mapsto {\rm div}_\lambda\,X_f.
$$

Exercise 1. $M_\lambda$ is a Poisson vector field.

Exercise 2. The difference $M_{\lambda_1}-M_{\lambda_2}$ is an Hamiltonian vector field for any pair of volume forms $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$.

(This allows to regard $[M_\lambda]\in H^1(\mathcal M,\pi)$.)

Exercise 3. $[M_\lambda]=0$ if and only if there exists a volume form $\lambda$ such that $\lambda$ is preserved by all Hamiltonian vector fields.

More details can be found in the above Wikipedia page (and probably, in the references therein).

Comment: Also see this book: https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-31090-4